# android how to call startActivityForResult inside an adapter

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I have an adapter class :

```
public class AdapterAllAddress extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
    public AdapterAllAddress(Context context,
            ArrayList<AllAddressesGroup> groups) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

I want to call `startActivityForResult` when a button click , I know I can call `startActivity` like this:

```
context.startActivity()
```

but i am looking for activity with results, how please ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourNewActivity.class);
        ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, resultCode);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am trying it, would you wait please

Comment: yea my second activity is opening but onActivityResult in my adapter is never getting called why is this happening ??

Comment: If someone needs it, onActivityResult() in the activity that provides the context will be called.

Comment: onactivityResult called but all the ids of that view becomes null.

Comment: @Preet which view?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan   all the ids within calling fragment. In my case i am startingactivityFor Result in Utils class by doing this ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, resultCode);
When it comes to onActivityResult of Calling Fragment , all ids (textview, buttons) etc becomes null. If i call activity from Fragment then it works fine, but i need it in Utils as it  is going to call at multiple places.

Comment: @Preet please post a new question and let me, I'll try to help according to the Available time

Comment: @WilliamKinaan please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54685955/onactivityresult-not-getting-called-in-fragment-where-intent-pass-from-adapter-c?noredirect=1#comment96166108_54685955

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to point a detail which i faced in my case  **E/ActivityThread(31584): Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.test/activities.MainActivity}**  most probably you are passing getApplicationContext() to the adapter's constructor . In order to avoid this you must provide "**CallingActivity.this**" to the adapter's constructor as the **context** object , keep this in mind .