# OnActivityResult not getting called in Fragment where intent pass from adapter class

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, onactivityresult

So in my adapter class, I would like to allow user to capture image

```
 fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        try {
            val captureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            (context as Activity).startActivityForResult(captureIntent, 1)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        Log.d("MyAdapter", "onActivityResult")
    }
```

I want the `onActivityResult` in a fragment class get called, but it doesn't.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        val imageListAdapter : ImageListAdapter?=null
        imageListAdapter?.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data)
                if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
                {
                    longToast("called")
                }else{
                    longToast("no")
                }
            }
```

There are no toast displayed. How to solve ?

I realize the `onActivityResult` works if I put in one of my Activity class, but I want to put at Fragment class !

Comment: Downvoters should explain why !

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: @NileshRathod if I put the onActivityResulty in one of the activity class, it works. But I want it call in fragment ! Is it because of this line ?  `(context as Activity)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49704422/7666442 and this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/44622657/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod my `startActivityForResult` need to call in Adapter class

Comment: Why don't you move your `dispatchTakePictureIntent()` inside your activity and call `startActivityForResult` from fragment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188414/discussion-between-tony-and-nilesh-rathod).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Comment: @shkschneider added super.onActivityResult but still no luck

Comment: Your problem is about the context and who calls startActivityForResult (which tells who will receive the result). It is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment and others. You just opened two duplicated questions IMO.

Comment: "added super.onActivityResult but still no luck" make sure to read the entire answer. First part was about super, the second part was not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as nikita said you should call `startActivityForResult` from fragment if you want to get results in fragment.

> I want to call startActivityForResult in adapter class, so I would
>   need context as Activity
>   Then create OnItemClick interface make your fragment implement it and pass it in a constructor to your Adapter. Then when a user clicks on an item call interface method

```
interface OnItemClickListener{
   onClick(item:T)
}

Foo: Fragment, OnItemClickListener{
...
    onClick(item:T){
        startActivityForResult...
    }
...
    initAdapter(){
        Adapter(listener=this,...)
    }

}
```

And in your adapter

```
...
itemView.setOnClickListener{
    listener.onClick(item)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort but it doesnt help. I have found a solution. Can you delete your answer so I can delete my post?

Comment: @Tony post your solution, it may help others

Comment: Is it impossible  to  call startActivityForResult from adapter class and onActivityResult in fragment ???

Comment: @Tony you can pass fragment (this) instead of context. and then call fragment.startActivityForResult(..)

Answer (score 1):

If you want fragment's `onActivityResult()` to be called, call `startActivityForResult(intent, id)` from fragment, not from activity (try pass fragment reference to adapter).

Also, make sure you haven't overridden activity's `onActivityResult()` or call `super.onActivityResult()` in activity.

Comment: I want to call startActivityForResult in adapter class, so I would need `context as Activity`