# Call startActivityResult in adapter and call onActivityResult in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, startactivityforresult

In adapter class, user can capture image when `holder.image` is clicked. I have set `onActivityResult` in Fragment, but it not getting called.

**Fragment**

```
 grid.setAdapter(ImageListAdapter(getActivity(), listOfImagesPath))
     ....

  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        val mAdapter: ImageListAdapter?=null
        mAdapter?.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        longToast("abc")
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            longToast("hello")
        } else {
            longToast("bye")
        }
    }
```

**Adapter**

```
 class ImageListAdapter(
        private val context: FragmentActivity?,
        private val imgPics: List<String>?
    ) : BaseAdapter() {

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return position
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            if (imgPics != null)
                return imgPics.size
            else
                return 1;
        }


        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

            var holder: ItemHolder
            var convertView = convertView

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null)
                holder = ItemHolder()
                holder.image = convertView!!.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
                holder.image?.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add)
                holder.image?.setColorFilter(R.color.colorGainsboro, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

                convertView.tag = holder

            }
            holder = convertView?.tag as ItemHolder
                  ....
            holder.image?.setImageBitmap(bm)
                }
            }

            holder.image?.setOnClickListener{
                dispatchTakePictureIntent()
            }
            return convertView
        }

        private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
            try {
                val captureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                context?.startActivityForResult(captureIntent, 1);
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
            Log.e("MyAdapter", "onActivityResult")
        }

        internal class ItemHolder {
            var image: ImageView? = null
        }
    }
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Which activity type you're using as base, AppCompatActivity?

Comment: Try to use host activity instead of fragment. From its onActivityResult invoke function of your adapter

Comment: @sinek Fragment()

Comment: @ArtemBotnev sorry,dont get it

Comment: Make sure to use extend your activity from AppCompatActivity and call super.onActivityResult if you ever override it.

Comment: @sinek This is my Fragment class `class CreateFragment : BaseFragment(true)`

Comment: and BaseFragment `abstract class BaseFragment(var showBottomNavigation: Boolean) : Fragment() {`

Comment: Isn't that the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54685955/onactivityresult-not-getting-called-in-fragment-where-intent-pass-from-adapter-c that you just asked earlier ?

Comment: @shkschneider Do you know what is the issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnActivityResult not getting called in Fragment where intent pass from adapter class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54685955/onactivityresult-not-getting-called-in-fragment-where-intent-pass-from-adapter-c)

Comment: @shkschneider added `super.onActivityResult` but still no luck :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you call startActivityForResult on your activity's context.

```
 private val context: FragmentActivity?,
 context?.startActivityForResult(captureIntent, 1);
```

You should use instead your Fragment's context if you want to get results there..

```
 private val fragment: Fragment?,
 fragment?.startActivityForResult(captureIntent, 1);
```

So you should pass your fragment reference to the adapter.

Comment: If i pass Fragment, I will get error on this line `grid.setAdapter(ImageListAdapter(getActivity(), listOfImagesPath))`

Comment: @jguerinet required fragment found fragmentActivity

Answer (score 1):

@sinek is right, you need to call `startActivityForResult()` from the `Fragment` instance instead of the activity. This requires passing in the `Fragment` instance to your adapter and fixing the old `context` calls as a result:

```
class ImageListAdapter(
    private val fragment: Fragment,
    private val imgPics: List<String>?
) : BaseAdapter() {

    ...

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        var holder: ItemHolder
        var convertView = convertView

        if (convertView == null) {
            // Here I am simply using the parent Context, as parent will never be null
            //   (Notice how I changed ViewGroup? to ViewGroup above)
            //   But if you prefer you can use fragment.context
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null)
            ...
        }

        ...

    }

    private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        try {
            val captureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            fragment.startActivityForResult(captureIntent, 1);
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, in your Fragment:

```
grid.setAdapter(ImageListAdapter(this, listOfImagesPath))
```